# Python-OpenCV Image Recognition

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I am new to the computer vision area and  i have been given this task,
I need to recognize an amount of images with a camera as soon as they enter the camera focus, this images would be scanned previously and stored in some sort of database.(maybe the key-points collection to each image)
well, i've been doing some research and found that SIFT may do the trick but i don't know how to use it properly, i need to do this on `Python-opencv`

**Note:** I already found examples in which I can get the key-points on an image using `SIFT`, but the code is very confusing to someone who does not know the language, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com) is a good page for you to get started and learn the basics along the way.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Totoro